# Run a function in its entirety before moving to next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I want to click a button, which will pull some data from Firebase, then I want to go to the next activity, passing an array that contains the Firebase data. I still can't wrap my head around asynchronous code, and I was hoping someone could help me out with the simplest way to accomplish this.

I've experimented with runblocking, suspend functions, await and async, but I can't seem to get it right. Here's my on click listener:

```
btn_games_quiz.setOnClickListener {

    listenForQuestions()

    val intent = Intent(this, QuizActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("questionArray", questionArray)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

And here's listenForQuestions:

```
private fun listenForQuestions(){

    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM")
    val formatted = current.format(formatter)
    val currentMonth = QuizActivity.months[formatted.toInt()]

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/quizzes/$currentMonth")

    ref.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

        override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                val questionItem = p0.getValue(Question::class.java)

                if (questionItem != null) {
                    questionArray += questionItem
                }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        }

        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        }
    })

}
```

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try Using thread.
new Runnable ();

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running this in a coroutine.

For asynchronous programming using coroutines, please have a look at this link.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html

Comment: I'm aware it's probably something to do with a coroutine. I've been directed to documents such as the one you've linked before but to no amount of success. No matter what I seem to do, be it define suspend functions, use runBlocking, whatever, every single time, when the code gets to "onChildAdded" it moves on and does something else. All I need to do is to execute that onChildAdded before anything else, but I can't seem to do that.